# How can I get the camera to pause on 3 objects on the x axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I am a new student working on a class project.  I have 1 script attached to the camera in my only scene.   I want the camera to pause over the 1st object, scroll to the 2nd object and pause then scroll to the 3rd object and pause then end.  Putting this code in the UPDATE, the camera never stops.  Here in the START, it hesitates around 15 sec and then it goes right to the last object, then the function stops.  Note the delay set for 10 seconds.  I tried putting the code in a function and calling the function from START… but no good.   What am I doing wrong?  HELP ME OB1....

One more thing...  Is START the best place to play sound?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// I want the camera to pause over the 1st object, scroll to the 2nd object and pause 
// then scroll to the 3rd object and pause then end.  Putting this code in the UPDATE
// the camera never stops.  Here in the START, it hesitates around 15 sec and then it 
// goes right to the last object, then the function stops.  Note the delay set for 10 
// seconds.

public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;      // How fast to move the camera
    public int moves;        // How many moves to make
    public float MyWait;     // How long to pause over object


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(MyDelay());
        for (int y = 1; y <= 2; y++)           // go to the next two objects
        { 
            for (int i = 1; i <= moves; i++)   // Move the camera to the next position
            {
                Camera.main.transform.Translate(new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                Debug.LogFormat("moves = {0} ", i);
            }
            StartCoroutine(MyDelay());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator MyDelay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10.0f);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should place the functionality of your code in your coroutine instead of it being a simple delay. If this question isnt answered by tomorrow, ill take a closer look and write some code from my computer instead of here on my phone. Also i dont recommend placing this in your update, since it doesnt need to be.

Comment: Also note that you could add an animation to your camera and play that animation.

Comment: Thank you....   that would be a big help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing this code on your camera and place all the game objects you'd like the camera to move to in the Objects list. If you'd like the camera to be a little further back so it can see the object, create a new Vector3 instead of simply giving the exact position and then give that new Vector3 the x, y and z of the iterating object and then add distance to which ever axis you'd like for the camera to be distanced from the object.

```
public float MyWait = 5;     // How long to pause over object
public float speed = 5f;      // How fast to move the camera
public List<GameObject> Objects;      //List of each object for the camera to go to


void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(MoveToObject(0));
}

IEnumerator MoveToObject(int iteratingObject)
{
    //Wait for however many seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(MyWait);
    bool atDestination = false;

    //Move the camera until at destination
    while (!atDestination)
    {
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Objects[iteratingObject].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);

        if (transform.position == Objects[iteratingObject].transform.position)
            atDestination = true;
    }

    //Continue iterating until moved over all objects in list
    if(iteratingObject != Objects.Count - 1)
        StartCoroutine(MoveToObject(iteratingObject + 1));
}
```

Comment: All of the objects are 3D planes with images on them.  They are all along the x axis.  I want the camera to move along the x axis and pause over each object.  I have assigned a tag to each of the planes.  Lets say the tags are Image1, Image2, Image3.  So how do I add the objects to the list and where.  The camera is looking at Image1, right now.

Comment: OK…  Call me stupid, but I really don’t know how to add a vector3 to the camera.  The camera is looking at Image1, right now and is at the perfect distance to view the image.   I hope this will not change.

It looks as if your code will find the images no matter where they are on the scene....  that is SO COOL....  I am SO excited....  Can’t wait to get it working.  I just need to know how to add the images to the list, and add the vector3 if needed.

Comment: I already explained how to do that? Instead of transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, Objects[iteratingObject].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed); write down Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, new Vector3 (Objects[iteratingObject].transform.position.x, Objects[iteratingObject].transform.position.y, Objects[iteratingObject].transform.position.z - distanceFromObject),Time.deltaTime * speed); where distanceFromObject would be a public variable with how far away you'd like to be from the object.

Comment: Note that i wrote these comments from my phone and may need adjusting. And to place the coordinates just add the gameobjects youd like the camera to move to in the Objects list found in the inspector of the camera.

Comment: Nothing is showing up in the inspector...  Not even MyWait or speed,  and I am getting an error message : "The type or namespace name `List`1' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"  pointing to the line 

public List<GameObject> Objects;   with a red line under List<GameObject>

Is this one of those tweeks?

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: Again, all im posting is from memory, and i may be inaccurate but close to the answer with these comments as i am not on my computer.

Comment: figured the Generic out on my own but the camera never moves.  I'll play with it. Should we move this to chat?

Comment: For the camera to move, that script must be a component of the camera and the objects you would like the camera to move over must be in the Objects list.

Comment: The script is a component of the camera and the images are in the list.  I dragged them from the Hierarchy to elements 0, 1 and 2 of the list.

Comment: Not quite....  I moved the camera Off the first image and ran again...  the camera DID move to the first image But then stops there

Comment: the if statement is not working.  atDestination never gets set to  true.  I added some debug statements and the one in the IF never shows up.

Comment: Right, because the y value isn't the same, you'll need to check with the new value since the y on both vector3's aren't the same. Once you check that it should work.

Comment: An easy way would be to just check both x position of both vector3's

Comment: WORKED LIKE A CHARM!!!!!    You are the man Alox....  The next time you come to Atlanta....   Drinks are on me.....   Thank you.....  That is so cool

Comment: Lol, all that for an accepted answer, well anyways, im glad it worked, be sure to accept it as the answer if it helped lol

Comment: To the left of the answer, there are upvotes and downvotes and for the author of the question there is an accept answer button.

Comment: Yes, perfect, thank you, have a good day, its almost midnight for me haha, good night.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to put some code in the Update function for this to work smoothly.
Time.deltaTime will only really make sense in an Update function, using it here and trying to do everything in the Start function won't work.  Also setting the Translate transform will instantly set the position to the given value.  Look up linear interpolation (lerp).

I would suggest you have a member that you use to track the current state, i.e. which object you're looking at, but an Enum of states might be easier to read.

Then you can keep a member for how long you've been in that state, which you can increase in the Update.
Then within the Update you can check whether it is time to change state or update your moving camera.

Good luck!

Comment: I have never used Unity or c# before and never programmed in an OOL.  so it's like you're speaking a foreign language to me.  It would be helpful to know how the code should look in order for this to work.  I do appreciate your input, user2287379, because I know you truly want to help.  I Thank You for that.